# Merging Columns in such a way that rows with duplicate elements are separated by commas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

This is the input dataframe that I'm having.

[image: Input DataFrame]

And this is the output that I want:

[image: Output DataFrame]

As you can see, both the dataframes are merged on the column Key1 in such a way that the row with common elements are separated by commas.

I have tried using merge but it doesn't give the correct output.

```
mer = pd.merge(df,df, on='Key1', how='inner')
```

Is there a specific way to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert values to strings and join unique values by `,` in custom lambda function:

Solution for working with missing values in `Key1` in oldier pandas versions with replace by temp values:

```
df1 = (df.fillna({'Key1': 'missing'}) 
         .groupby('Key1')
         .agg(lambda x: ','.join(pd.unique(x.astype(str))))
         .reset_index()
         .replace({'Key1':{'missing':np.nan}}))
```

Solution for last pandas versions:

```
df1 = (df.groupby('Key1')
         .agg(lambda x: ','.join(pd.unique(x.astype(str))))
         .reset_index())
```

Comment: Actually the output has 1 row missing. The row with first name of John Smith and key2 as 456. You can check that in the question.

Comment: @Amit - Can you check edited answer? Added `.reset_index()`

Comment: Yes, I added reset_index but still that 1 row is missing. I think it's because key1 is NaN for that row. Is there a way to still add that row in the output? We can maybe try filling in random value for that row? But the problem is that even in the output, that random value will be there.

Comment: @Amit Ok, understand. I add solution for this, anothe idea is upgrade pandas for working with NaNs and use original answer.